# Convert complex TabView into Sheet utilizing Annotations

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have somewhat of a complex thing that I am attempting, but I don't know how I could take this approach, so I wanted to reach out and see if someone might be able to assist me.

**Current Execution**:
When a user clicks on a annotation on the map, it opens a TabView with information from  `MapPinDetailView`, and when another annotation is clicked, it opens the other TabView.

https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-a0fecfbaba.gif

**What I'm attempting to do**:
When an annotation is clicked, open a sheet with using the `MapPinDetailView` and then when another annotation is clicked, overwrite the current sheet with the new sheet with `MapPinDetailView`.

---

Here is the code for `WorldView`:

```
struct WorldView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                if model.selectedItemId != 0 {
                    activeMapAnnotationDisplay
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var activeMapAnnotationDisplay: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $model.selectedItemId) {
                if let item = model.selectedItem {
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: PlaceDetailView(place: item),
                        label: {
                            MapPinDetailView(item: item)
                                .tag(item.id)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .onChange(of: model.selectedItemId) { newID in
                model.places.setShowToFalse()
                let index: Int = model.places.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == newID})!
                model.places[index].show = true
                model.selectedItemId = model.places[index].id
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    locationManager.defaultRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
                        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                            latitude: model.places[index].lat,
                            longitude: model.places[index].long),
                        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
                            latitudeDelta: 0.5,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.5
                        )
                    )
                    model.isLiked = UserDefaultsManager.isInclude(model.selectedItemId)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `MapPinDetailView`:

```
struct MapPinDetailView: View {
    var item: Place
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 14) {
                KFImage(URL(string: "https://bridgehunter.com/photos/13/49/134972-L.jpg")!)
                VStack(spacing: 2) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                    Text(item.excerpt)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need the navigation view when the tab is clicked, I just want to be able to click on a annotation and open a sheet, and then able to overwrite that sheet when another annotation is clicked.

I don't know how to take this approach, so I would appreciate some help!

Comment: It isn’t complex at all look into “.sheet(item:)”

Comment: @loremipsum, what would I possibly hook the sheet into? I can't use it on the `if mode.selectedItemId` or the `activeMapAnnotationDisplay` function, I'm just lost on what I can possibly hook the sheet onto.

Comment: To the view that displays all the annotations. The annotations would have a tap gesture that set the item. You only need one sheet for all the annotations.

Comment: Interesting, the annotations are based on `if model.selectedItemId != 0 { activeMapAnnotationDisplay }` which displays the TabView, I'll have to look into how to incorporate a tap gesture on such, since it based on a visible ID.